# Meteor angular-ui-router routing logic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

Hi when a user is directed to one page I want to perform a logic check to see if there are any entries in a collection that are missing an attribute and redirect the user if so. Here is sort of my idea of how the code should look but I can't seen to get the subscribe to work in the routes.js file

routes.js

```
.state('pendingVisits', {
    url: '/pendingVisits',
    templateUrl: ()=> {
      if (Meteor.isCordova) {
        return '/packages/visitry-mobile/client/visits/pending-visits/pending-visits.html';
      } else {
        return '/packages/visitry-browser/client/visits/pending-visits/pending-visits.html';
      }
    },
    controller: 'pendingVisitsCtrl as pendingVisits',
    resolve:{
      feedback: function($location){
        Meteor.subscribe('visits');
        var v = Visits.findOne({feedbackId});
        if(v){
          $location.url('/visits/'+v._id+'/feedback');
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Basically I'm trying to do something similar to Uber's UI where if there is no feedback for the last event I display the feedback page. Thanks for the help. Let me know if you need any more code or information.

Comment: I read something that said putting this type of logic in the router is an anti-pattern because you would need to wait for the data to load. Can anyone confirm this? It seems like if I put the logic in the pendingVisits controller that view would flash briefly before the user was redirected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this with Tracker.autorun() Here is the solution I used:

```
resolve:{
  feedback:function($location){
    const visits = Meteor.subscribe('visits');
    Tracker.autorun(()=>{
      const isReady = visits.ready();
      var visitNeedingFeedback = Visits.findOne({feedbackId:null})
      if(isReady && visitNeedingFeedback){
        console.log("Yes lets go to feedbacks");
        $location.url('/feedback/'+ visitNeedingFeedback._id);
      }else{
        console.log(`Visits data is ${isReady ? 'ready' : 'not ready'}`)
      }
    })
  }
}
```